# Python scheduling- how can I pulling data out of HTML every 5 min

Tags: python, schedule

I'm practicing to build a project. I want get the stock value every 5 min, if the price is the same with setting price, I will got an e-mail and desktop notification, but now I have some trouble...I don't know how to fix this...

```
import bs4
import requests
import schedule
import time
import smtplib
import email.message
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
from function import send_email

stock_no = input('Plesae insert stock no：')
set_price = input('Please set notification price:')


def job():
    links = 'https://histock.tw/stock/%s' % stock_no
    response = requests.get(links)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    tittle = soup.find('h3').get_text().strip()
    li = soup.find('span', id="Price1_lbTPrice").span.get_text()
    msg_text = tittle + 'stock value is  ' + li


schedule.every(5).minutes.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)

if set_price is li:
    send_email(msg_text)
    toaster = ToastNotifier()
    toaster.show_toast("Stock value notification",
                       msg_text,
                       duration=10)
```

there's something wrong...like this

[This is my problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L9PrC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You have declared "li" and "msg_text" inside of the "job" function, that means that these variables are just available inside the "job" function.

There are many ways to solve this problem, I will just propose one to try to help you:

```
import bs4
import requests
import schedule
import time
import smtplib
import email.message
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
from function import send_email

stock_no = input('Please insert stock no：')
set_price = input('Please set notification price:')


def get_stock_price():
    links = 'https://histock.tw/stock/%s' % stock_no
    response = requests.get(links)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    tittle = soup.find('h3').get_text().strip()
    li = soup.find('span', id="Price1_lbTPrice").span.get_text()
    return li 
    
schedule.every(5).minutes.do(job)

while True:
    schedule.run_pending()
    time.sleep(1)
    current_price = get_stock_price()

    if set_price == current_price:
        msg_text = tittle + 'stock value is  ' + current_price
        send_email(msg_text)
        toaster = ToastNotifier()
        toaster.show_toast("Stock value notification",
                       msg_text,
                       duration=10)
```

I didn't test the code above but it may be useful to you understand the error that you posted.

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I try to fixing code from your answer, it's working now!

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I fix this question from Tito's answer. I post these code, hope it can help somebody have the same question.

```
import bs4
import requests
import schedule
import time
import smtplib
import email.message
from win10toast import ToastNotifier
from function import send_email

stock_no = input('Please insert stock no：')
set_price = '%.2f' % int(input('Please set notification price:'))


def get_stock_price():
    links = 'https://histock.tw/stock/%s' % stock_no
    response = requests.get(links)
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'lxml')
    tittle = soup.find('h3').get_text().strip()
    li = soup.find('span', id="Price1_lbTPrice").span.get_text()
    return li, tittle


schedule.every(5).minutes.do(get_stock_price)

while True:
    try:
        schedule.run_pending()
        time.sleep(1)
        current_price = get_stock_price()[0]

        if set_price == current_price:
            msg_text = get_stock_price()[1] + \
                'stock value is  ' + current_price
            send_email(msg_text)
            toaster = ToastNotifier()
            toaster.show_toast("Stock value notification",
                               msg_text,
                               duration=10)
    except:
        print('It is not working...')
```